# Metodo optimizado para un webrequest

Tags: c#

Necesito mover todo esto

```
    System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://service.mx:8080/sdpapi/request/");

                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.Method = "POST";

string postData = "OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=488E-AEE9-0FED26EAA258&INPUT_DATA=" + sendXML;
                byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
                os.Close();
                System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                if (resp == null) return null;
                System.IO.StreamReader sr =
                      new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

                string respuesta = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                return respuesta;
```

Y acomodarlo con estos parametros

```
<add key="posData" value="OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=488E-AEE9-0FED26EAA258&INPUT_DATA="/>
<add key="url" value="http://service.mx:8080/sdpapi/request/"/>
```

Ya que he tratado de hacerlo dejando solo los string pero aun asi no me aceptan los metodos, necesito implementar los metodos anteriores.

Se los agradeceria muchisimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias definir la entrada como ser

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="postData" value="OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=488E-AEE9-0FED26EAA258&INPUT_DATA=" />
      <add key="url" value="http://service.mx:8080/sdpapi/request/" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

enonces si agregar la referencia a `System.Configuration` usarias

```
  string postData= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["postData"];
```

asi tomarias los datos de la configuracion

[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings?view=netframework-4.8)

el codigo quedaria

```
string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"];
var req = WebRequest.Create(url);

req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";

string postDataConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["postData"] 
string postData = postDataConfig + sendXML;

byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

//resto codigo
```